# How to change the background color of a specific table header and font color of a specific column in a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable

Is there a way to change the background color of the 3 circled table headers of a `JTable`?

I also want to change the font color of all the 3 circled columns to red.

An image of my table is down below. Thanks.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Igr2n.png]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The way I know of is to create a `TableCellRenderer` that will handle the coloring of the foreground and background color.

You could create a simple coloring scheme where the color doesn't change. You often see this in tables with alternating colored rows. You could also use it for "conditional formatting". For example, highlight a cell if a value falls under a certain value. With a cell renderer, you will have better control of this.

Here is a link to [Oracle's tutorial on renderers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer).

Lastly, since your question specifically asks to do this on specific cells, the link documentation states that

> *To specify a **cell-specific renderer**, you need to define a JTable subclass that overrides the getCellRenderer method. For example, the following code makes the first cell in the first column of the table use a custom renderer*:

```
TableCellRenderer weirdRenderer = new WeirdRenderer();
table = new JTable(...) {
    public TableCellRenderer getCellRenderer(int row, int column) {
        if ((row == 0) && (column == 0)) {
            return weirdRenderer;
        }
        // else...
        return super.getCellRenderer(row, column);
    }
};
```

Comment: @camickr I know this is normally how it is done. But if I want to "adorn" a table header with colored cells, I could add a label and color the label. After all, the header data should be static. So, not adding it to the table model might be OK. Perhaps I should've been more specific.